# EasySVG library php addText function problems with locating the text

Tags: php, svg, coordinates, vector-graphics

i have misunderstanding about locating the text in svg file via EasySVG.
I have an image in svg format 1200x1400px.
[image]

I need to put the text to place by setting coordinates.

```
require '../../lib/easysvg/src/easySVG.php';
$svg = new EasySVG($pattern);
$svg->setFont($fontPath, 32, '#000000');

$ppo = 3.779527559;
$left=1200/$ppo;
$top=1400/$ppo;
//there i convert values for pxs to mms

$svg->addText("Text", $left, $top);
file_put_contents('result.svg',$svg->asXML());
```

The result is next image, but i really do not understand why text included in (1536;-404).
Position of the "rectangle" is the same as at the 1st photo.
I have never worked with vector imgs or inkscape, i admit that these coordinates could be "transformed" according to some relativities or smth like that.

[image]

Comment: what is the value of $pattern?

Comment: @RobertLongson it`s path of svg file i use as a background

Comment: Yes and we'd need to know exactly what it is in order to answer this question.

Comment: What does the resulting SVG/XML look like? Please add that to your question.

Comment: @RobertLongson sorry for taking so long to answer, i have found the solution, btw thank for trying to help me

Comment: @chrwahl i have updated the question with solution, sorry for taking so long to answer

Comment: @RobertLongson ok ,sorry about bad practice, im newbee here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution!

Finally my problem was solved by recalculating of x and y of added text. Here is the code that helped me.

```
$sizeCoef = 2.7069767442;
$newSize = $size/$sizeCoef;
//if i put 43(for example) as font size to ->setFont() method it drawed me 116.4 px height text

$ppo = 3.779527559;
//1 mm = 3.779... pxs

$shift = 1.133786;
// i do not know why, but i calculeted that if i try to shift text position,
//for example, to 100 pxs righter and 100 lower, i get text, moved by 88,2
//in both directions instead of 100 (i think it`s the solution of my problem) 

$x = $left/$ppo*$shift;                    
$y = $top/$ppo*$shift;
// here i recalculate coordinates to mms

$svg->addText($text,$x,$y);
```